# Screenshot will not copy to clipboard in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity desktop. How can I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, ubuntu-14.04, screenshot

I have been able to take screenshots without issue until today.  Now screenshots are being produced but will not copy to the clipboard.  If I use the screenshot app and save the image to a file this works.  However if I hit the copy to clipboard button, I cannot paste into the document that I am working on.  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: I found this when I upgraded, and it has not improved in 15.04. I have found that many of the other keyboard short-cuts don't work either; changing the short-cut or adding `gnome-screenshot -c` as a custom short-cut doesn't work either, though the command works when typed in a terminal. It seems that there is a serious problem with keyboard short-cuts. All I can suggest is that you add a launch icon to the panel, which means that the panel will be in the screen-shot, unless you use the `-w` option to copy a single window.

Comment: I've seen a few attempted fixes on the forums, but all seem to target gnome.  Since I have Unity desktop, I thought that these were not applicable to me.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: I avoid Unity, so I can't check, in order to confirm or deny. I have a feeling that Unity uses some of the Gnome infrastructure - certainly they can coexist as alternative log-in environments. Type `gnome-screenshot -c` from a terminal: if the program exists, or you can install it, then it will probably work, so try it and see.